# C function to get all sums of an array using addition and subtraction

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, permutation

What would be the best way (in C) to get all sums of N numbers in an array, by using addition and subtraction?

For example (N = 3):

```
arr[] = [30, 14, 2]

results:
-30-14-2 = -46
-30-14+2 = -42
-30+14-2 = -18
-30+14+2 = -14
 30-14-2 = 14
 30-14+2 = 18
 30+14-2 = 42
 30+14+2 = 46
```

As can be seen, there are 2^N solutions.

I also noticed that the addition an subtraction symbols alternate in the same way as binary counting (000 001 … 110 111), which might be useful.

Probably a recursive approach would be best, but I find it very hard to think recursively.

Therefore, I hope someone can explain to me what the best strategy would be to tackle this problem.

——————————

EDIT:

I have a working Python code, but this uses sets `set()`, which aren’t available in C. (`arr` is an array containing all numbers.)

```py
out = set()
out.add(0)
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    tmp = set()
    for j in out:
        tmp.add(j + arr[i])
        tmp.add(j - arr[i])
    out = tmp
print(out)
```

——————————

EDIT:

With replacing the sets by arrays and making a few small changes, I got it working. Thanks to everyone who commented!

Comment: This is an opinon: You shouldn't do this recursively, rather simply in two loops... one that loops over operations (because they can be done with an accumulator) and the second that loops over the values and you will have your result without running into memory problems.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) I'd consider focussing on this as a [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) problem.  2) I don't know if recursion is "better", but anything you can do with recursion, you can also do with loops.  3) I'm not sure there are necessarily 2^N "solutions".  For example, "a+b" == "b+a" (they're "the same"); but "a-b" <> "b-a" (they're  two different "solutions").

Comment: Well, this is a short program. What have you tried? Could you start writing a program? Keep one array with `bool negative[3] = {0};` and calculate sum of `array[i] * (negative[i]?-1:1)` at each step and then each step increment the next value in `negative` and repeat, up until all values in `negative` are true. For example. `he best strategy` why "the best"? Do any. There are endless examples of permutations in C using recursion available online - research them, surely they come up in google.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your reply. With ‘the best’ I meant the simplest to understand and write, since I already have a working Python version of this code. However, in Python I use sets (`set()`), which aren’t available in C.

Comment: Recursion does not have to be difficult. You just have to acknowledge that while you don't know the *entire* solution, you may know *a* solution of a partial problem, and a way to derive a solution to the full problem from the solutions to the partial problem. It's [easy](https://www.godbolt.org/z/4brT4vE1P).

Comment: Instead of a set, just use an array. How important is performance here?

Comment: is there an upper limit on number in the array and the size of array?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes ofcourse! Stupid of me not to think about that…

Comment: If you have a solution, consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem.

Comment: interesting to note the bottom half of the results are (-1) of the top half. Looks like you only need to do half the math, then (-1) that for the entire solution.

Comment: I think that only saves you the first iteration though.

Comment: @bbuy-01 why did you remove your Python code? That was helpful...

Comment: @bbuy-01 please don't rollback the edits repeatedly without giving a reason. Your code should stay.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that's not quite how the site works. Once you've posted code, it belongs to the community, so you can't sabotage your own post like this. Anyone can view the edit history, anyway, even without an account.

Comment: @bbuy-01 please see also [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253214/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-poster-deleting-their-code-in-an-edit-to-avoid-pla) (and linked threads)

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where recursion seems preferable to a data structure because the exponential nature of the problem means there's no risk of a stack overflow on any value of `n` you could realistically test, yet you can take advantage of the stack's implicit storage capabilities.

The recursive logic can be written very directly using an index `i`. The base case is when `i >= n`; print the sum you've accumulated. Otherwise, subtract the `i`th element from the sum and recurse on the rest of the numbers list without `i`. In a second branch, add the `i`th element to the sum and recurse on the rest of the numbers list without `i`. You could also shift elements off the array using a pointer instead if `i` as pointed out in the comments.

Note that this procedure will include duplicate results, so if you want to eliminate those, your original set idea is worth pursuing.

It's generally poor design to mix IO and logic in functions, but for simplicity's sake, I'll break that rule here:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_possible_sums(int nums_len, int *nums, int sum, int i) {
    if (i >= nums_len) {
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    else {
        print_possible_sums(nums_len, nums, sum - nums[i], i + 1);
        print_possible_sums(nums_len, nums, sum + nums[i], i + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {30, 14, 2};
    print_possible_sums(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), arr, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-46
-42
-18
-14
14
18
42
46
```

Comment: Maybe I should feel flattered, but you *could* have mentioned your [inspiration](https://www.godbolt.org/z/4brT4vE1P)?

Comment: @EOF I'm not sure I follow your hint, but the pointer idea is a nice improvement, thanks for sharing.

Comment: It's just truly incredible, how similar our programming styles are.

Comment: Are you suggesting I copied it? If so, that's not the case and I'm not sure how I'd have found that link. The problem is pretty straightforward so the solution is pretty direct, so I'm not sure how much room for deviation there'd be.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an algorithm that performs this problem. Maybe what I wrote is not as efficient as possible (so maybe it can be improved) but at least it works.

Let me know if it's okay.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 4
void cycle(int arr[MAX]);
int toRepeat(int arr[MAX], int s);

int main(){
    int arr[MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cycle(arr);
}

void cycle(int arr[MAX]){
    int a, ris;
    a = pow(2, MAX);
    for (int i= 0; i < a; i++){
        ris = toRepeat(arr, i);
        printf(" = %3d \n", ris);
    }
}

int toRepeat(int arr[MAX], int s){
    int pos = 0;
    int ris = 0;
    int a;
    bool flag;
    a = pow(2, MAX);
    if (s < a/2) {
        ris += arr[pos];
        printf("+%d", arr[pos]);
    } else {
        ris -= arr[pos];
        printf("-%d", arr[pos]);
    }
    pos++;
    
    for (int i= 2; i < a; i = i * 2){
        for (int j= 0; j < i/2; j++) {
            if (s%i == j) {
                ris += arr[pos];
                printf("+%d", arr[pos]);
                pos++;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flag){
            ris -= arr[pos];
            printf("-%d", arr[pos]);
            pos++;
        }
        flag = false;
    }
    return ris;
}
```

Output:

```
+1+2+3+4 =  10
+1-2+3+4 =   6
+1+2-3+4 =   4
+1-2-3+4 =   0
+1+2+3-4 =   2
+1-2+3-4 =  -2
+1+2-3-4 =  -4
+1-2-3-4 =  -8
-1+2+3+4 =   8
-1-2+3+4 =   4
-1+2-3+4 =   2
-1-2-3+4 =  -2
-1+2+3-4 =   0
-1-2+3-4 =  -4
-1+2-3-4 =  -6
-1-2-3-4 = -10
```

Comment: For grins, I compiled your code with the original data set (I needed to make a few minor changes), and confirmed it gives the expected result: `+30+14+2 =  46 
+30-14+2 =  18
+30+14-2 =  42
+30-14-2 =  14
-30+14+2 = -14
-30-14+2 = -42
-30+14-2 = -18
-30-14-2 = -46`

Answer (score 0):

Me too, me too!

Keep one array with `bool negative[3 + 1] = {0};`. Calculate sum of `array[i] * (negative[i]?-1:1)` at each step. Each step increments the next value in negative as if it would be a binary number. The loop ends when the highest element `negative[3]` is true - so we want through all possibilities.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int calc_sum(size_t len, const int vals[len], const bool negative[len]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += vals[i] * (negative[i] ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return sum;
}

bool *sequence_init(size_t len) {
    // error checking omitted
    return calloc(len + 1, sizeof(bool));
}

bool sequence_continue(size_t len, bool t[len + 1]) {
    assert(t);
    const bool go_on = !t[len];
    if (!go_on) {
        // automatically free on loop end
        free(t);
    }
    return go_on;
}

void sequence_next(size_t len, bool t[len + 1]) {
    assert(t);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len + 1; ++i) {
        if (!t[i]) {
            t[i] = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            t[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const int vals[3] = { 30, 14, 2 };
    const size_t len = 3;
    for(
        bool *sequence = sequence_init(len);
        sequence_continue(len, sequence);
        sequence_next(len, sequence)
    ) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            printf("%2d*%d %c ",
                sequence[i]?-1:1,
                vals[i],
                i + 1 != len ? '+' : '='
            );
        }
        const int sum = calc_sum(len, vals, sequence);
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

The code outputs:

```
 1*30 +  1*14 +  1*2 = 46
-1*30 +  1*14 +  1*2 = -14
 1*30 + -1*14 +  1*2 = 18
-1*30 + -1*14 +  1*2 = -42
 1*30 +  1*14 + -1*2 = 42
-1*30 +  1*14 + -1*2 = -18
 1*30 + -1*14 + -1*2 = 14
-1*30 + -1*14 + -1*2 = -46
```